# How to join two rows into just one in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL query where the idea is to join two rows into one.
When performing

```
select * from caixa
```

I get the following result:

```
id   money    open                closed        fun  type  situation
--------------------------------------------------------------------
13    10      08/09/2018 18:55                   1    E     1
37    -473                  09/09/2018 17:01     1    F     1
40    0       09/09/2018 17:08                   1    E     2
41    0                     10/09/2018 17:09     1    F     2
```

The idea is to join the two rows where the situations are the same
getting for example:

```
money     open                   closed        fun  type  situation
--------------------------------------------------------------------
-473      08/09/2018 18:55  09/09/2018 17:01    1    E      1
```

Comment: You need to specify how to aggregate the other columns (`money`, `fun` and `type`) when grouping by `situation`.

Comment: will you have more than 1 rows with same `situation` value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use aggregate function to make it

```
SELECT MIN(money) as money ,MAX(open) as open,
       MAX(closed) as closed,fun,MIN(type) as type,
       MIN(situation) as situation
FROM caixa
GROUP BY fun
```

Comment: this even works, but I did not want to compare the date with max, I would have to do something to get it if it is different from empty ?

Comment: What will you want to do if there are many different dates? `MAX` can filter the empty string or `NULL` then get the values

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the table with itself

```
SELECT O.money as open_money, C.money as closed_money,
       O.open as open, C.closed as closed,
       O.fun as open_fun, C.fun as closed_fun,
       O.type as open_type, C.type as closed_type
FROM caixa O, caixa C
WHERE O.id <> C.id 
AND O.situation = C.situation
AND O.open IS NOT NULL 
AND C.closed IS NOT NULL
```